# Place n points while maximizing the minimum distance

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a distance `d` (going from `0` to `d`) and 2 points `s` and `e` in between which no points can be placed (placing points on `s` and `e` is fine, it's not allowed to place points between them).

Place `n` points such that the distance between each point is as large as possible (distribute them as evenly as possible).

Output the minimal distance between  2 points.

Graphic representation, place `n` points on the black line (it's a 1-dimensional line) so that the smallest distance between each 2 points is as large as possible (an absolute error of up to `10^(-4)` is allowed).

[image: Graphic representation]

Examples:

- d=7, n=2, s=6, e=7, Output is: 7.0000000000
- d=5, n=3, s=5, e=5, Output is: 2.5000000006
- d=3, n=3, s=0, e=1, Output is: 1.5000000007
- d=9, n=10, s=5, e=6, Output is: 1.0000000001
- d=6, n=2, s=1, e=6, Output is: 6.0000000000
- d=5, n=3, s=4, e=5, Output is: 2.5000000006

My approach:

I tried looking at the intervals separately, distributing points (ideal distribution, `lengthOfInterval`/`n`) on the first and second interval (`0` to `s` and `e` to `d`) and inspecting all distributions whose number of points sum up to `n`, I would store a (distribution, largest minimal distance) pair and pick the pair with the largest minimal distance. I don't know how to work with the `10^(-4)` tolerance (how does this part even look in code?) and am not sure if my approach is correct. Every suggestion is welcome.

I'm stuck on this question :/

Comment: I would use a similar approch for now but be careful that the gap could be really small. you would end up with 2 points really close, so not evenly separated. As for the tolerance, isn't it for the correction of the homerwork (or exercise) ?

Comment: Please check out O(1) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **binary search** over the possible sizes of gaps between points (from `0` to `d`) to converge to the largest minimum gap size.

To determine the viability of any given gap size, you basically try to place points from the left and from the right and see whether the gap in the middle is big enough:

- Determine how many points can be placed left of `s` (which is `s/gapSize + 1`).
- Determine how many points will then be required to be placed to the right of `e`
  (which is `n - points on left`).
- Determine how far inwards each side will go.
- Check whether the points on the right fits in the gap `[e, d]` and whether there's at least `gap size` difference between each side.

Code for this: (note that I worked with number of gaps instead of points, which is just 1 less than the number of points, since it leads to simpler code)

```
double high = d, low = 0, epsilon = 0.000001;
while (low + epsilon < high)
{
    double mid = (low + high)/2;
    int gapsOnLeft = (int)(s/mid); // gaps = points - 1
    if (gapsOnLeft + 1 > n)
        gapsOnLeft = n - 1;
    int gapsOnRight = n - gapsOnLeft - 2; // will be -1 when there's no point on the right
    double leftOffset = mid*gapsOnLeft;
    // can be > d with no point on the right, which makes the below check work correctly
    double rightOffset = d - mid*gapsOnRight;
    if (leftOffset + mid <= rightOffset && rightOffset >= e)
        low = mid;
    else
        high = mid;
}
System.out.println(low);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/CljK7K).

The time complexity is `O(log d)`.

---

The problem with your approach is that it's hard to figure out how big the gaps between points are supposed to be, so you won't know how many points are supposed to go on either side of `(s, e)` as to end up with an optimal solution and to correctly deal with both cases when `s` and `e` are really close together and when they're far apart.

Comment: Note that this prints 0.9999 instead of 0.8333 for `d=9, n=10, s=5, e=6` on the basis that you can place 10 points on every integer 0-9 resulting in a difference of 1 between each point. Not sure why this would be considered incorrect or whether 0.83 was just a typing or implementation mistake by the person who made the examples.

Comment: Fixed it, good catch, I am currently trying to understand your solution, looks correct! Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Shouldn't epsilon be 0.0001?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Epsilon should be less than or equal to 0.0001. I tend to prefer going slightly lower because floating point arithmetic is inexact, at least when it doesn't affect running time too much.

Comment: I think the complexity is log(d/epsilon), does this still count as log(d)?

Comment: @maraca Since epsilon is constant, it doesn't affect the big-O complexity. It's still `O(log d)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Binary search**

Its very easy to find the number of points you can place if the minimum separation distance b/w any pair `l` is given.

If l=d, then at the most only 2 points can be placed. 
.. 
... 
....

so just do a binary search on l.

A crude implementation goes like this.

```
low,high=0.00001,d
while(high-low>eps):
    m = (low+high)/2
    if((no. of points placed s.t any pair is at most m units away) >=n):
        low=mid
    else:
        high=mid
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Your approach does not always work (and you're not doing it as fast as you could) see the 3rd bullet point for one that works (and uses the given 10^(-4)).

- If `[s, e]` is small and well-placed, then the optimum is just distributing evenly on the whole segment, best value is now `d/(n-1)`. But you'll have to check that none of your elements is between `s` and `e`.
- Your approach works if `s` and `e` are "far enough".

You can do it faster than what you seem to suggest though, by lookign for the best splitting between the two segments in time `O(1)`: if you put `n1` (`1<=n1<=n-1`) elements on the left, you want to maximize `min(s/(n1-1), (d-e)/(n-n1-1))` (one of these quantities being possibly `+infinity`, but then the other is not). The maximum of that function is obtained for `s/(x-1) = (d-e)/(n-x-1)`, just compute the corresponding value for `x`, and either its floor or ceiling is the best value for `n1`. The distance obtained is `best = min(s/(n1-1), (d-e)/(n-n1-1))` Then you put `n1` points on the left, starting at `0`, separated by distance `best`, and `n-n1` on the right, starting at `d`, going left, separated by `best`.

If the distance between the last point on the left and the first on the right is smaller than best, then you have a problem, this approach does not work.

- The complicated case is when the two previous approaches failed: the hole is small and not well placed. Then there are probably many ways to solve the problem. One is to use binary search to find the optimal space between two consecutive points. Given a candidate space `sp`, try distributing points on the line starting at 0, spaced by `sp`, as many as you can while remaining below s. Do the same on the right while staying above e and above `(last on the left + sp)`. If you have successfully placed at least n points in total, then `sp` is too small. Otherwise, it is too big.

Thus, you can use binary search to find the optimal `sp`as follows: start at sp possibly in [max(s, d-e)/(n-1), d/(n-1)]. At each step, take the middle `mid` of your possible segment `[x, y]`. Check if the real optimum is above or below `mid`. According to your case, look for the optimum in `[mid, y]` or `[x, mid]`. Stop iff `y-x < 10^(-4)`.

The two previous cases will actually also be found by this method, so you don't need to implement them, except if you want the exact optimal value when possible (i.e. in the first two cases).

Comment: `"one of these quantities being possibly +infinity"` - division by 0 is undefined, not infinity.

Comment: @Dukeling I know. What I mean is that, when coding, he should allow putting 1 element only on one side, and give the value +infinity to the distance between two nodes on this side, so that the minimum of the two sides is the value of the other one. Anyway he won't need this part of the code if he does not want the exact optimal value even in this case. What I'm trying to explain there is that he does not need to compute all possible separations between the two sides to find the best one, which would take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty tricky, except for the simple case (no point lands in the gap):

```
double dMin = d / (n - 1.0);
if (Math.ceil(e / dMin - 1) * dMin <= s)
    return dMin;
```

Let's continue with the edge cases, placing one point on one side and the rest of the points on the other one:

```
dMin = Math.min((d - e) / (n - 2.0), e); // one point at 0
double dm = Math.min(s / (n - 2.0), d - s); // one point at d
if (dm > dMin) // 2nd configuration was better
    dMin = dm;
```

And finally for two or more points on both sides:

```
// left : right = (x - 1) : (n - x - 1)
// left * n - left * x - left = right * x - right
// x * (left + right) = left * n - left + right
// x = (left * n - left + right) / (left + right) = (left * n) / (left + right) - 1 
int x = s * n / (d - e + s) - 1;
if (x < 2)
    x = 2;
for (int y = x; y <= x + 2 && y < n - 1; y++) {
    double dLeft = s / (y - 1.0);
    double dRight = (d - e) / (n - y - 1.0);
    dm = Math.min(dLeft, dRight);
    if (dm > e - s) { // dm bigger than gap 
        if (dLeft > dRight)
            dLeft = e / ((double) y);
        else
            dRight = (d - s) / ((double) n - y);
        dm = Math.min(dLeft, dRight);
    }
    if (dm > dMin)
        dMin = dm;
}
```

This would be **O(1)** space and time, but I'm not 100% positive if all cases are checked. Please let me know if it worked. **Tested against all the test cases**. The above works for `n >= 2`, if n equals 2 it will be caught by the first check.

Comment: The 0.833333 comment in your code made me think mine was wrong, but so far it is holding up, the correct answer is 1.0.